# Vanilla forum - Как убрать копирайт?

Tags: php, cms, html

Как убрать копирайт скрипта форума Vanilla в стандартном шаблоне 2.0.18 версии (by Mark O'Sullivan)?

Comment: Там, можно открыть страницу в штмл коде, найдите этот кусок и удалите.

Comment: Я согласен что вопрос может быть задан весьма некорректно. Но и вы идите лесом с таким ответом...Я сколько файлов там перерыл там везделибо php либо tpl - и Html там нету.

Comment: это не ответ, а просто рекомендация где искать, там же есть админка, в админку редактор страниц, он открывается для редактирования в штмл, там весь код, а если найти не можешь - значит плохо ищешь, они там точно есть

Comment: Если я не могу найти значит - ты хренова шаришь. Ты видно только в Joomla или DLE копался...В Vanilla нету редактора хтмл страниц и шаблонов в админке. Хоть в вики залез бы глянул что это такое...А то просто так от балды ответ кляпаешь.

ps. Не ответ? А комент к вопросу оставить не додумался?

Comment: (facepalm) я вообще только с пхпББ3 работал
зы если это не комент, то что?

Comment: Под копирайтом подразумевается "powered by Vanilla"?

Comment: @Gorets - а ты весёлый баклан :)

@knes - типа того.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В стандартной поставке форума, открываете такие файлы

applications/dashboard/views/atom.master
applications/dashboard/views/rss.master
applications/dashboard/views/default.master.php
themes/EmbedFriendly/views/default.master.tpl
themes/mobile/views/default.master.tpl
 (открыть можно любимым текстовым редактором, но желательно не Word:) )
В этих файлах находится powered by Vanilla и заменяется на нужную запись.

P.S. юридические аспекты на совести заменяющего.